# Doubt about isomorphic groups!

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ and $H$ be two isomorphic groups.According to my present knowledge,both $G$ and $H$ have same properties and need not be distinguished.But my book says that $G$ and $H$ can behave differently if they are subgroups of a large group.I can't understand why it is ?

Comment: What do u mean by saying `...behave...`? Also `...large group...`?

Comment: They can behave differently *as subgroups*. Being isomorphic as abstract groups is a weaker condition than, say, being conjugate in a larger group.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan can u please give me an example?

Comment: @BabakS. Although I have copied this from my book but I think large means cardinality of group can be much more than subgroups cardinality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Example: The "larger group" is $\mathbb{Z}$ with addition.  Let $A=p\mathbb{Z}$ for any prime $p$, and $B=k\mathbb{Z}$ for any non-prime non-zero $k$.  Then $A$ and $B$ are isomorphic as groups.  However $\mathbb{Z}/A$ has no proper non-trivial subgroups.  $\mathbb{Z}/B$ has proper non-trivial subgroups.  In this way $A$ and $B$ act differently as subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Is $\mathbb{N}$ under ordinary addition is really a group?

Comment: @ArpitKansal, Sorry, I meant $\mathbb{Z}$.  Change made.

Comment: now it works perfectly.Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Another example - let $G$ be any *non-abelian* group. Then the subgroups $H:=\{(g,1) : g \in G\}$ and $K=\{(g,g) : g \in G\}$ of the direct product $G \times G$ are isomorphic. However, $H$ is normal in $G \times G$, but $K$ is not.

Comment: I had never even contemplated the possibility that $K$ would not be normal! +1, just for pointing that out!